# Collection view performBatchUpdates crash randomly in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am making chat application. for chat Ui, I used jsqmessageview controller. when we load previous messages then give the following error:-
**[JSQMessagesCollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3698.52.10/UICollectionView.m:5867
2019-02-25 17:25:35.553375+0530 Calmex[288:12648] ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert item 25 into section 0, but there are only 25 items in section 0 after the update'**

we used following code :-

```
 var indexPaths: [AnyObject] = []
 var arraysizeOfCollectionview : Int = 0
 if(isloadmore)
 {
   self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates
   ({
            indexPaths.removeAll()

            let lastIdx = messages123.count - 1

            for i in 0...lastIdx
            {
                print("index path -->\(IndexPath.init(item: i, section: 0))")
                indexPaths.append(IndexPath.init(item: i, section: 0) as AnyObject)
            }
            self.collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths as! [IndexPath])

            self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout(with: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext())

            arraysizeOfCollectionview = arraysizeOfCollectionview + indexPaths.count
  },
    completion: {(finished) in
  })
}
else
{
  arraysizeOfCollectionview = self.messages.count
}
```

we have total row count in "arraysizeOfCollectionview" and return in the collection view.

```
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
  numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
  {
    // Return the number of messages

    return arraysizeOfCollectionview

}
```

so anyone has a solution for this random crash then please help me or any idea of related to load the previous message using collection view then please help me.

thank you.

Comment: Looks like you can run your code several times in a row.

Comment: you are always updating 0... lastIdx does it make sense?

Comment: Misha Vyrko,
have you any solution for load previous messages when scroll on top side?like whats app.